# Permission problem installing virtualenv on Linux with apt

Tags: linux, installation, virtualenv, pip

I'm using linux mint 14, and installed virtualenv via apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
$ virtualenv --version
> 1.7.1.2
```

The problem is that it's an old version. When I install it via PIP, it installs the version I want, but it is only acessible via root user:

```
$ pip install virtualenv --upgrade (fails)
> ...OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/virtualenv'
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv --version
> bash: /usr/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
$ sudo virtualenv --version
> 1.8.4
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the permissions for the file:

ls -alrt /usr/bin/virtualenv

The file needs to have execute permission for user, group and all.

Comment: Pip didn't create this file:
`ls -alrt /usr/bin/virtualenv
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
sudo ls -alrt /usr/bin/virtualenv
ls: cannot access /usr/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory`